# How to bind a SelectionBackgroundColorKey to a LinearGradientBrush?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I'm trying to change the SelectionBackground of the WPF DataGrid on the fly. I tried binding it and that didn't work. I finally found the following but I still can't supply a dynamic "White Stop".
What I would really like is to bind straight to a [LinearGradientBrush](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.lineargradientbrush%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that I can lighten and darken as the situation changes but I'll settle for how to bind the "White Stop" to something that changes dynamically.

```
            <DataGrid.Resources>

                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SelectionBackgroundColorKey" />
                <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
                    <GradientStop Color="{Binding Source={StaticResource SelectionBackgroundColorKey}, Path=Color}" Offset="0.0" />
                    <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0.3" />
                    <GradientStop Color="{Binding Source={StaticResource SelectionBackgroundColorKey}, Path=Color}" Offset="1.0" />
                </LinearGradientBrush>

                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SelectionTextColorKey" Color="Black" />
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}" Color="{Binding Source={StaticResource SelectionTextColorKey}, Path=Color}" />
            </DataGrid.Resources>
```

CodeBehind snippet:

```
    private void DataGridReservationsSelectionChanged(object argSender, SelectionChangedEventArgs argEvtArgs)
    {
        Color localBackgroundColorKey = ApplicationSettings.ReservationNormalSelectedBackgroundColor;
        Color localTextColorKey = ApplicationSettings.ReservationNormalSelectedTextColor;

        Reservation localReservation = dataGridReservations.SelectedItem as Reservation;

        if (localReservation == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (localReservation.IsArrived)
        {
            localBackgroundColorKey = ApplicationSettings.ReservationArrivedSelectedBackgroundColor;
            localTextColorKey = ApplicationSettings.ReservationArrivedSelectedTextColor;
        }
        else if (localReservation.IsCanceled)
        {
            localBackgroundColorKey = ApplicationSettings.ReservationCanceledSelectedBackgroundColor;
            localTextColorKey = ApplicationSettings.ReservationCanceledSelectedTextColor;
        }
        ... etc...
        ((SolidColorBrush)dataGridReservations.Resources["SelectionBackgroundColorKey"]).Color = localBackgroundColorKey;
        ((SolidColorBrush)dataGridReservations.Resources["SelectionTextColorKey"]).Color = localTextColorKey;


    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out what I wanted.
If I add more Key colors to the DataGrid Resources I can use them in the LinearGradientBrush.

i.e.

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="SelectionBackgroundColorKey" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="SelectionBackgroundWhiteStopKey" /> <!-- Added a WhiteStopKey to the resources -->
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
    <GradientStop Color="{Binding Source={StaticResource SelectionBackgroundColorKey}, Path=Color}" Offset="0.0" />
    <GradientStop Color="{Binding Source={StaticResource SelectionBackgroundWhiteStopKey}, Path=Color}" Offset="0.3" /> <!-- Use the WhiteStopKey in the LinearGradientBrush -->
    <GradientStop Color="{Binding Source={StaticResource SelectionBackgroundColorKey}, Path=Color}" Offset="1.0" />
</LinearGradientBrush>
```

... then, in the code...

```
((SolidColorBrush)dataGridReservations.Resources["SelectionBackgroundColorKey"]).Color = localBackgroundColorKey;
((SolidColorBrush)dataGridReservations.Resources["SelectionBackgroundWhiteStopKey"]).Color = localBackgroundColorKey.Lighten(1.7F);
```

NOTE: Color.Lighten() is an extension method I wrote, not a Framework method.

To paraphrase: Desperation is the mother of invention.